# Python - Creating installable packages from different unique project structure

Tags: python, configuration, setuptools, python-packaging, project-structure

My goal is to establish a project structure that will limit future headache. The project I am working on has 3 different packages that need to be installable and tested, the structure looks something like this:

```
my-project
    - src
        - __init__.py
        - widely_used_module_1.py
        - widely_used_module_2.py
        - widely_used_module_3.py
        
        - package_2
            - __init__.py
            - package_2_module.py
    
    - package_3
        - __init__.py
        - package_3_module.py

    - tests
        - src_tests
        - package_2_tests
        - package_3_tests

    - pyproject.toml
    
    - setup.cfg 

    - setup.py
```

Note that `\src` needs to be an installable package itself. There are modules within the `\src` directory that are used throughout the entire project, in each of the packages.

To my knowledge, I have a few options. I can leave the project as it is and pull my hair out trying to create and test 3 different packages in this format, OR I can create 3 different subdirectories within `\src`. In the latter option I would package the "widely_used_modules" into their own directory, keep `package_2` how it is, and add `package_3` into `src`.

There is a lot of coupling between these packages as `package_3` acts as a "wrapper" around `package_2` & `package_3`, so refactoring subdirectories within `src` will take considerable time. But I'm willing to go this route if it will make life easier in the future.

My main issue with leaving the project structure in its current state is that I am not sure how to write the `pyproject.toml` or `setup.cfg` to create 3 different installable packages.

If anyone is aware of some existing projects that are structured in a similar way, please direct me to them. Also open to any other suggestions.

Comment: I think the most easy way, when you want to have 3 separate packages, is to create 3 separate packages. I.e. 3 src directories, 3 pyproject.toml, and so on. If you really need 3 packages, or if it should rather be one single package with all pros and cons cannot really be deducted from the information given

Comment: Thanks for your input, of the two options you presented, the first makes the most sense. Again the main goal is to just create 3 different installable packages, all of which will need to import from each other. If you could provide some more context on how the pyproject.toml's and setup.cfg for this case should look, I will accept it as an answer

Comment: _all of which will need to import from each other_ means you of some sort of cyclic dependencies? In that case, you cannot really have 3 independent package. A python package will - upon installation - install also its required dependencies. But with cyclic dependencies that will not work. Would need more details about the internals of your code.